# How to query if a ClearCase view is dynamic?

Tags: clearcase

How can I tell if a ClearCase view is static, web or dynamic?

The best I've found so far is to attempt `startview`, but that has some side-effects…

The ideal approach wouldn't have to (time out failing to) contact the view server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

best way is with lsview command:

```
ct lsview  –l/ong  –ful/l <view>
```

This can give you, when and by whom the view was created, last modified, and last accessed
Permissions for the view owner, view group members, and others
With the –full option, reports the following additional properties:
Whether the view is a dynamic view or a snapshot view
Whether the view is read-only or writable

ClearCase Web view you created or the UCM project you joined appears in the ClearTeam Navigator.

Comment: You mean "-pro/perties -ful". Which is perfect, thanks! For the record, it shows "webview" for web views.

Answer (score 0):

The only option in [`clieartool lsview`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsview.htm) which gives the nature of the view is `-pro` (for properties)

```
cleartool lsview -pro viewTag
```

But it isn't the proper way, consider a web view means no '`cleartool`'.

Another simple way is the absence of `cleartool`: That means ClearTeam 8.x (or CCRC for 7.x), web views, not snapshot ones.

If you have the "thick" client (the Rational ClearCase client) installed in addition of the ClearTeam Explorer, (since [CT8.x now supports dynamic views as well](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.help.ic.doc/topics/c_whatsnew.htm)), then right-clicking on the view and selecting its properties is easier than a `cleartool` command.

A snapshot view has its root on the hard drive, a dynamic one is mounted on the MVFS drive (by default `M:\` on Windows, `/views` on unix), so if you start a view and it appears on those mounting point, it is a dynamic view.

Another possibility is to display the config spec (`cleartool catcs -tag view-tag`): if there are no loading rules, it is a dynamic view.